# Reversing the effect of a \newline with the next command?

Tags: spacing, macros, line-breaking, harvard-style

I'm using the `harvard` package and the `agsm` bibliography style.  I'm aware that there are alternatives, e.g., `natbib` plus `har2nat`, and I will be looking into those in the not-too-distant future, but at the present I'm just trying to tidy up a bibliography that I've already got.

When the entry in the bibtex file contains a URL field, it's included in the bibliography entry in the document using `\newline\harvardurl{...}`, e.g.:

```
\harvarditem[Baader et~al.]{Baader, Calvanese, McGuinness, Nardi \harvardand\
  Patel-Schneider}{2003}{DLH:2003}
Baader, F., Calvanese, D., McGuinness, D.~L., Nardi, D. \harvardand\
  Patel-Schneider, P.~F., eds  \harvardyearleft 2003\harvardyearright , {\em
  The Description Logic Handbook: Theory, Implementation and Applications},
  Cambridge University Press, New York, NY, USA.
\newline\harvardurl{http://dx.doi.org/10.2277/0521781760}
```

Now, I've often redefined the `\harvardurl` command in order to format the URL differently.  Now I want to remove all the URLs from the bibliography entirely.  I can remove all lines matching `\newline\harvardurl{...}` from the `.bbl` file, but I'd have to do that after every `bibtex` run.  The `\newline` is actually getting inserted by `agsm.bst`:

```
FUNCTION {write.url}                                                                                                                   
{ URL empty$                                                                                                                           
    { skip$ }                                                                                                                          
    { "\newline\harvardurl{" URL * "}" * write$ newline$ }                                                                             
  if$                                                                                                                                  
}
```

It looks like the only way I could avoid the `\newline` is by making `URL` somehow be empty.  So, as the quick workaround, is there something I can do with the definition of `\harvardurl` to remove the effect of `\newline`?

As a minimal example that doesn't require the `harvard` package, here's a list with two entries and a `\newline\harvardurl{...}` in each one:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Don't display the URL text.  How 
% can we also counteract the previous
% \newline?
\newcommand{\harvardurl}[1]{}

\begin{document}

\begin{list}{}{}
\item Baader, F., Calvanese, D., McGuinness, D.~L., Nardi, D. \&
Patel-Schneider, P.~F., eds (2003) , {\em The Description Logic
  Handbook: Theory, Implementation and Applications}, Cambridge
University Press, New York, NY, USA.
\newline\harvardurl{http://dx.doi.org/10.2277/0521781760}

\item Baader, F., Calvanese, D., McGuinness, D.~L., Nardi, D. \&
Patel-Schneider, P.~F., eds (2003) , {\em The Description Logic
  Handbook: Theory, Implementation and Applications}, Cambridge
University Press, New York, NY, USA.
\newline\harvardurl{http://dx.doi.org/10.2277/0521781760}
\end{list}

\end{document}
```

[image: bibliography with too much space]

One quick approach that produces initially acceptable results is to define as `\\[-2\baselineskip]`, but this feels pretty hacky:

```
\newcommand{\harvardurl}[1]{\\[-2\baselineskip]}
```

It looks OK, at least intially;  I'm not confident that this doesn't have some edge case where things break.

[image: better using a negative baselineskip]

Comment: You might try doing `\renewcommand\harvardurl[1]{\unpenalty\unskip\unpenalty}`

Comment: Of course @egreg's answer is great but just for completeness, you may also want to consider editing the `.bst` file (so the newline never gets inserted). You only need to do this once and you can even just put the modified version in your working dir so it replaces the globally installed one only for that project. Another workaround is using a different field for the url e.g. `note`

Comment: @Bordaigorl Those are certainly alternatives (and I quoted the bst in the question), though I don't really like having to maintain custom versions of other people's code.  But the bounty isn't for the *solution*; it's for the explanation of the process of getting it. (La)TeX, to many (myself included) often feels like a very-hard-to-debug language, and the answer that explains that process (using `\show`, `\xshowcmd`, etc.) is very useful.  Cf. "give a man a fish … teach a man to fish …."

Comment: Sure! just mentioning alternatives to undoing the spacing after the fact =) egreg's answer is stellar as always, can't beat that!

Comment: there's also an unnecessary space after the year.  you might want to look at that too.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Good catch;  I think that might have been a copy and paste error when I was creating the MWE.  I don't seem to see it in the version I've got now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The final effect of `\newline`, when used in horizontal mode (which is the case here) is to issue

```
\nobreak\hfil\break
```

Since `\nobreak` and `\break` are `\penalty10000` and `\penalty-10000` respectively, you should be able to remove the three items by

```
\renewcommand{\harvardurl}[1]{\unpenalty\unskip\unpenalty}
```

At least this works in the example you gave.

---

How can you find what's the effect of `\newline`? There are a few ways. Here's what I did. I run LaTeX from the terminal on this unfinished file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\show\newline
```

This opens an interactive session; the first answer is

```
> \newline=macro:
->\protect \newline  .
l.5 \show\newline
```

I hit return and at the prompt typed

```
\xshowcmd\newline
```

because the answer made it clear that `\newline` is a robust command; the answer was

```
> \newline =\long macro:
->\@normalcr \relax .
<recently read> \newline
```

Then again return and `\show\@normalcr`, getting

```
> \@normalcr=\long macro:
->\let \reserved@e \relax \let \reserved@f \relax \@ifstar {\let \reserved@e 
\vadjust \let \reserved@f \nobreak \@xnewline }\@xnewline .
<*> \show\@normalcr
```

OK, `\@normalcr` looks for a `*`, which we don't have. In any case, the next command we want to look at is `\@xnewline`; so `\show\@xnewline` gives

```
> \@xnewline=macro:
->\@ifnextchar [\@newline {\@gnewline \relax }.
<*> \show\@xnewline
```

Good; we don't have a `[`, so I did `\show\@gnewline`:

```
> \@gnewline=macro:
#1->\ifvmode \@nolnerr \else \unskip \reserved@e {\reserved@f #1}\nobreak \hfil
 \break \fi .
<*> \show\@gnewline
```

This is a bit complicated, but we're not in vertical mode, so LaTeX executes

```
\unskip\reserved@e{\reserved@f\relax}\nobreak\hfil\break
```

Now we go back and look at how `\reserved@e` and `\reserved@f` had been defined by `\@normalcr`: nothing strange, they're `\relax`. So the effect is to remove a space `\unskip` (and this is good for our purposes) and insert

```
\nobreak\hfil\break
```

The commands `\unpenalty` and `\unskip` are TeX primitives, you find a description in the TeXbook or in TeX by Topic (`texdoc texbytopic`). Basically, `\unpenalty` removes the last item if it is a penalty, `\unskip` removes the last item if it is a skip. With the proposed redefinition of `\harvardurl` TeX is left with

```
\nobreak\hfil\break\unpenalty\unskip\unpenalty
```

Actually it has already executed the first three commands, appending a penalty item, a glue item and another penalty item to the current list; so the first `\unpenalty` removes the penalty due to `\break`, then the last item is the result from `\hfil` that's removed by `\unskip` and then the last item in the list is again a penalty: hurray, `\unpenalty` gets rid of it.

Comment: Thanks!  This looks like the proper way of doing this, and it seems to work in my real document as well.  I'm going to read more about `\unpenalty` and `\unskip`, but I wonder if you could, for the sake of increasing my latex-debugging-fu, give a word or two about how you determined that the final effect of `\newline` in this context is `\nobreak\hfil\break`?

Comment: I don't need the whole breakdown either;  I'm just curious.  An answer along the lines of "take a look at `\debugcommand`" would be fine. :)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Why not making the story complete? ;-)

Comment: so this happens in the dragon's den....

Comment: @percusse This was easy. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg This is very nice;  I'll be going through this in more detail.  The reason I mentioned that a minimum is OK is that I'm more active on StackOverflow, and there it's easy to run into "help vampires"; I wanted to be clear that I wasn't demanding the whole picture; I just needed a push in the right direction.  This is _very_ helpful though;  I'll be able to dig a bit deeper in the future. Thanks!

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor TeX is a macro expansion language; commands can change their meaning depending on the context. That was an example of how an analysis can be carried on; as you see, doing just `\show\@gnewline` could be misleading, because of the two “reserved" macros that have been given a meaning while processing the initial `\newline`.